# Regex commands not finding designated strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a small crawler to grab twitter handles. I cannot for the life get around an error I keep having. It seems to be the exact same error for re.search. re.findall and re.finditer. The error is `TypeError: expected string or buffer.`

The data is structured as followed from the CSV:

```
30,"texg",@handle,,,,,,,,
```

Note that the print row works fine, the test = re.... errors out before getting to the print line.

```
def read_urls(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = open('Data.txt', 'w')
    dict1 = {}
    for row in reader:
        print row   
        test = re.search(r'@(\w+)', row)
        print test.group(1)
```

Also not I have been working through this problem at a number of different threads but all solutions explained have not worked. It just seems like re isn't able to read the row call...

Comment: `row` is a list, not a string, since you're using `csv.reader`.

Comment: `row` in your for loop is a lsit of strings, [accroding to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). So, maybe try `test = re.search(r'@(\w+)', ' '.join(row))`. I'm not sure if this is the issue, so thats why I'm making it a comment

Comment: `test = re.search(r'@(\w+)', row[2]); if test: print(test.group(1))`

Comment: Why are you using a regexp? `csv.reader` parses the line into a list of fields. The twitter handle is always in `row[2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your code carefully:

```
for row in reader:
    print row   
    test = re.search(r'@(\w+)', row)
    print test.group(1)
```

Note that row is a list not a string and according to search documentation:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. **Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern;** note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

That means you should create a string and check whether `test` is not `None`

```
for row in reader:
    print row   
    test = re.search(r'@(\w+)', ''.join(row))
    if test:
        print test.group(1)
```

Also open file without `b` flag like

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read a list after you run the file through the reader.

```
import re

f = open('file1.txt', 'r')
for row in f:
    print(row)
    test = re.search(r'@(\w+)', row)
    print(test.group(1))
f.close()
```

https://repl.it/JCng/1

If you want to use the CSV reader, you can loop through the list.